# What happens to a user in a Google Compute Instance when their Google account is deleted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I've not been able to find much of a straight answer regarding what happens to a user's data in a Google Compute Instance when their Google account is deleted (example, `jane.doe@somedomain.com`). The following questions are what immediately comes to mind:

- Is the user (for example, user `jane_doe`) in the Compute Instance deleted from the machine?
- Is the user's directory (for example, `/home/jane_doe`) in the Compute Instance deleted from the machine?

Users seem to be created whenever an Instance is created, and I'm assuming that it is based on the users we have defined as `Owners` in the project, if it helps to add some clarity to my questions; I didn't create the users manually.

Additionally, users access the instances through SSH using the Google Console Cloud (Compute Engine -> VM Instances).

I know that their data in GSuite would be gone, but documentation doesn't seem to be all that clear about GCE. The main issue is we have some software that runs through a user's personal directory. If any of the above answers is 'yes', is there something we can do to possibly prevent this data loss?

Cheers.

Comment: you mean a GCE instance within the GCP account for the user?

Comment: I just want to mark a difference between the Compute and App Instances, as we're using Compute Instances. Sorry I might not be as familiar with some of the terms. Should I change something in my wording?

Comment: If I create a home directory for you - on an GCE instance within my GCP account - there is no way that is deleted when you delete your account.

Comment: As far as I understand, the home directories and/or users are created according to whomever has the corresponding role for GCE management (for example, I'm assigned as an Owner of the project, and so was the account we want to delete) at the time of the creation of the instance. If this is the case, then what you just said should hold true, correct? So long as there's still an owner, everything should continue normally. I just want to make sure I'm understanding this well enough before pushing that big red button.

Comment: Edit your question and include details on how you are using authorization (login) within your Compute Engine instance. For example, are you manually creating users within the Linux instance or are you using OAuth. More details please.

Comment: Sorry John Hanley, I'm not sure where I can check that. I'm not too experienced with the whole Google Cloud Suite so there's big gaps in my knowledge. Could you orient me so I can better set up the question?

Comment: There are many ways to login to a Linux instance. You will need to figure out the method you are using. There are common methods like console login, SSH, web server. Then there are services such as OAuth, LDAP, Active Directory, Kerberos, MySQL, etc. There are entire books on this subject. If you are using Google Accounts for login, then you are (usually) interested in your OAuth configuration. Google also has Identity Aware Proxy, etc that can control access.

Comment: We use SSH to access the Instances, so we just need to be logged in to our Google Account and belong to the project to make use of this functionality; it logs into the machine with a user according to who's accessing the Instance. Would that make it OAuth?

Comment: 1/2) Please be specific on how you are connecting with SSH. If you mean the Google Cloud Console (and no other method ever), then yes, deleting the IAM user deletes their access.

Comment: 2/2) If you mean using the CLI `gcloud`, then yes and or no. Google creates a private key and stores it in the user's home directory under `.ssh`. This key remains even if you delete the user in Google Cloud IAM later. This means that a "smart" end-user that knows GCP will be able to SSH into the GCE instance even if you delete their IAM account as the Linux login still exists. You will need to manually delete the user from the Linux system.

Comment: Note: If you have allowed existing users root (su) access, then they have the ability to create additional logins, which we call back-doors. To be certain, you need to audit the users on your Linux system.

Comment: Following the excellent John comment, my recommendation is change the firewall rule and to bloc the port 22 on public internet. Only authorize the (IAP IP range](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding). This feature required to be authorized on Google Cloud to open a secure tunnel and then to log into the VM. Without IAM authorization, and even if the user let "ssh backdoor" open, you are safe. If others backdoor are open.... audit your system

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm using the Google Cloud Console, not the CLI. It's fine if the access is lost, but what I'm most interested in is knowing if their data in the instances will remain, more specifically their files and directories.